# Converting .m to .mex for Octave speed-up

Tags: matlab, compilation, octave, mex

I have a `.m` script that runs rather slowly in Octave (about 2 minutes typically), and not quite so slowly in MATLAB (about 7 seconds), and I presume the performance would be enhanced by compiling the program to a `.mex` file (especially for Octave).  Unfortunately, the MATLAB compiler function `mcc` no longer supports the `-x` option to generate a `.mex` file.

Is there a workaround for this?

---

**Edit:** In response to the comments

Below code's purpose is to smooth a spectrum while leaving high power regions mostly intact. It does this by taking local averages with a window size that depends on the magnitude of the spectrum at a point.

I do this with just a simple `for` loop, which is why it's so slow (vectorizing won't work easily because it would require a matrix with so many elements as to exhaust the available memory.

I am working with sound vectors that have `~600,000` elements, so the matrix would need `~3*10^11` elements, which is even too big for a sparse matrix on my 32 bit computer.

```
function smoothsig=smoothnoise(sig,wins,method)
% Smooths a signal "sig", leaving hi power regions intact (mostly).
% "wins" is a window size for smoothing
% "method" determines the relative smoothing of various parts of the spectrum
% "method" can be a handle to any function <=1 on [0,1] 

mx=max(abs(sig)); mn=min(abs(sig)); range=mx-mn;
len=(size(sig)); len=len(1);

if ~(exist('method','var'))
    method=1;
end

winsize=round(wins* winfunction((abs(sig)-mn)/range,method) );
smoothsig=zeros(size(sig));

for k=1:wins
    winsz=min(k-1,winsize(k));
    smoothsig(k)=mean(sig(k-winsz:k+winsz));
end

for k=wins+1:len-wins
    winsz=winsize(k);
    smoothsig(k)=mean(sig(k-winsz:k+winsz));
end

for k=len+1-wins:len
    winsz=min(len-k,winsize(k));
    smoothsig(k)=mean(sig(k-winsz:k+winsz));
end

end

%-------------------------------------------------------------
function y=winfunction(x, method)
    % Determines the window function
    if isa(method, 'function_handle')
        y=method(x);
    elseif isscalar(method) & method==1         % Uniform window size
        y=ones(size(x));
    elseif isvector(method) & method(1)==2      % Sharp cutoff for window size
        y=x<method(2);
    elseif isvector(method) & method(1)==3      % Polynomial change
        y=(1-x).^method(2);
    end
end
```

---

- I'm not very familiar with C++, so I would prefer to do this in a more automated way than re-coding by hand in another language, if possible.
- I had not hear about `.oct` files, so I'll investigate that, but also see the above remark (I'm not fluent with C++).

Comment: Show us the code. Such huge performance difference between the two interpreters is abnormal.

Comment: Lacking the -x option simply means, that you have to do two steps. 1) Generate C/C++ code 2) Compile the C/C++ code.

Comment: If you're converting it to mex just because of the performance difference in Octave, then don't. Write an oct file instead which is more C++-ish and also more flexible. But I agree with @juliohm , first make sure you wrote the code "well". Matlab has JIT, and Octave does not (well, kinda of. Depends on how you build it) so if you don't write the way the language is designed you'll get a big performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to automatically generate C-code from your MATLAB code, and then compile this to a .mex file for speedup, this functionality now exists in the [MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/matlab-coder/) product rather than MATLAB Compiler.